# See current frame without an error

Tags: python

In Python, is there a way to see the current stack frame?  That is, I want to see a list of files which were called to get to my current location.

Essentially, I want to see

```
try:
  1/0
except:
  traceback.print_exc()
```

without actually raising an error.

Answer (score 2):

You want a stack trace, not a stack frame (the stack frame is one area in the stack holding e.g. the local variables of the current function). The [traceback](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html) module has various means to get a stack trace without raising an exception. To print a stack trace directly, use `traceback.print_stack()`.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  traceback.print_tb takes a traceback object right?  Is there a function in traceback that will get the current traceback?  Also, just for my clarification, I thought a traceback was just the stack at the point at which an error occurs, is that not right?  Will traceback.print_stack() work?

Comment: @Colin: You're right, you actually want `print_stack()` (which *is* a stack trace) - I'm just stupid and confused it :) Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You could use pdb and to add a breakpoint.

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Then user the **where** command to tell you where you are in the stack frame.